# URL.Action passing null, need integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, url.action

I'm in the process of building a simple website using MVC 4 and razor. I'm having trouble receiving an int from an url.action that is being filled on the fly. I have debugged and found that the id does have a value (the id happens to just be 1) but when it is passed it somehow becomes null.

The View portion:

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
  foreach (var e in Model)
  {
    <a href="@Url.Action("EventDetails", "Event", new{id = e.ID})">
      <div id="eventBox">
        <!-- stuff !-->
      </div>
    </a>
  }
}
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult EventDetails(int? eventID)
{
     if (eventID != null)
     {
         //stuff
     }
}
```

I really don't know what is happening behind the scenes to cause it to change to null and I need help. I'm using just the default routing provided by Visual Studio right now:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passing a route value named id

```
new { id = e.ID }
```

so change the method parameter name to match it

```
public ActionResult EventDetails(int? id)
```